# Bootstrap navbar custom height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to shrink the navbar height for mobile sizes.  What I've tried shrinks the navbar, but the JS menu doesn't function.  Any ideas?

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom { height:35px; }
```

Comment: what do you have so far? Are you using responsive layout that Bootstrap provides?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm using a media queries and was hoping to shrink the height when on mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download the [custom version](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) or you are using the `less` css, just change the `@navbarHeight` variable to desired height.

You can, of course, change it manually, but it will have to be done in multiple places. Use [`navbar.less`](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less) file to look for all the references where `@navbarHeight` is used.

I also didn't see the fact that you wanted to do it only in the mobile site.  The `.less` file for the navbar for the responsive design is [`responsive-navbar.less`](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-navbar.less). The height is the same for both desktop and mobile navbar, and there is nothing set specifically for the mobile one, but without a bunch of testing I wouldn't recommend changing it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a media queries with less?  and the above variable?

Comment: they use `.less` as the basis for the `.css` files that bootstrap compiles into. I updated my answer with a note about mobile.